# Listing types=other with javascript API

Tags: google-places-api

If i do a nearby search using type other via the URL, my businesses show up.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&types=other&radius=50000&sensor=false&location=40.805232,-74.464679&key=MY_KEY

But when i do the same search via the javascript API i get ZERO_RESULTS.

```
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address' : address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var request = {
                location : results[0].geometry.location,
                radius : '50000',
                "types": ["other"]
            };

            service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(dijit.registry.byId(
                    "map").get('map'));
            writeLog("GoogleMap.setupMap().getLocation searching, request="
                    + JSON.stringify(request));
            service.nearbySearch(request, loadPlaces);
        }

    });
```

Output:

GoogleMap.setupMap().getLocation searching, request={"location":{"jb":40.79676670000001,"kb":-74.4815438},"radius":"50000","types":["other"]}
GoogleMap.onLoadPlaces() status ZERO_RESULTS

Is there something else that has to be done to get the javascript api to return the same results as the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Are searches working at all in your JavaScript API? Is it only THIS one that doesn't work - or does in fact ANY search return ZERO_RESULTS?

Comment: When I use the URL you've posted above in my browser I ALSO get status ZERO_RESULTS. If I change types=other to, say types=store, I get results in my browser. I note "Other" is not listed as a "types" in the API documentation. I also note that if you use "type" rather than "types" then (as it is a typo and wrong) it acts like you didn't put any choice at all and returns ALL types. Could that have happened? The url you've given does not have this typo so maybe the above link is not the same as the one you originally tried it with?

Comment: types:[other] is supposed to allow you to display your places that you have created.  Its not well documented, but a known function.